# Git Subtree prefix path

Tags: git, github, git-subtree

I have a problem with GIT subtrees.

Let's see, I have a project A which consists of:

```
Project A
|_CodeFolder1
|_CodeFolder2
|_SharedFolder1
|_SharedFolder2
```

Let's say I make a new repo that just has *SharedFolder1* and *SharedFolder2*.So I remove those two folders from the main repo, and add them to the new shared repo, which would look like this:

```
SharedProject
|_SharedFolder1
|_SharedFolder2
```

I'm newbie to subtrees, but till now I achieved to pull/push from remote subtrees. But I'm having a problem. When I add the subtree, I must add a prefix, but I don't want to save the shared code in a different folder, like:

```
Project A
    |_CodeFolder1
    |_CodeFolder2
    |_SharedFolders
             |_SharedFolder1
             |_SharedFolder2
```

Which is what the `--prefix` makes whenever I try to add the subtree:

```
git subtree add --prefix=SharedFolders --squash shared master
```

Is there any way I can tell git that there's no prefix, or that the subtree must be saved in ProjectA directly, like in the first schema, without creating a new folder for the subtree?

I tried this command

```
git subtree add --prefix=/ --squash shared master
```

But there's always an error. Seems that subtree won't let me take the folders from the tree directly to my working path without creating a new folder for the shared files.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I got the answer. The correct syntax is:

```
git subtree add --prefix= --squash shared <branch>
```

And for pulling:

```
git subtree pull --prefix=/ --squash shared <branch>
```

Comment: The add does not work on git v2.17.1. The error message I get is "You must provide the --prefix option."

Comment: @penguins I'm getting the same error message in 2.25.1. This renders git subtree useless for this use-case.  I've also tried `--prefix=.` but get a similarly useless error: `prefix '.' already exists.`